# Laravel belongsToMany only works one way

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, pivot-table

I'm trying to make a many to many relation, in this example with user and role.

In User model I got this:

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'user_role', 'user_id', 'role_id');
}
```

In Role model I got this:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_role', 'role_id', 'user_id');
}
```

And my pivot table user_role:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('user_role', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
    }
```

Now when I do `$user->roles()->attach(1);` it makes a row in the user_role table. But the problem is when I want to access it: `$user->roles;` it returns nothing. It works with `$role->users;` but not the other way. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know about Laravel, but you must create and use a "many-to-many relationship" table between the two tables.

Comment: I am using many to many relationship example taken from Laravel documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved : Laravel 5.2.29**

make sure the table name is   **role_user**

```
    $user = User::find(1);
    $role = Role::find(2);
    // In this example I am passing in a Role object but $role->id also works
    $user->roles()->attach($role);
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: I tried both table names user_role and role_user but still same problem. `belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_role', 'role_id', 'user_id');` In this 2nd param means table name, 3rd means current model row in there and 4th means attched model row name

Comment: I have created the repo for you . clone the following repo :          [https://github.com/HashmatWaziri/laravel-5.2.29-manyToManyRelationship](https://github.com/HashmatWaziri/laravel-5.2.29-manyToManyRelationship)

Answer (score 0):

You have to reload the relationship after attaching like so

```
$user->roles()->attach($role);

$user->load('roles');
```